# What is the difference between the Australian 600 and 601 visas, for people who are eligible for both?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, australia, tourist-visas

I'm traveling to Australia in July and I've been looking into getting a visa.
I see two visa options, a 600 and a 601 that appear to be appropriate (I'm going for leisure and not for work).
The 600 costs 125 USD and the 601 costs 20 USD. Why would I opt for the more expensive option?
Will the 601 visa suffice?

Comment: Two reasons: (1) you might be planning to travel to Australia for longer than 90 days; (2) you might not be from one of the countries whose nationals can apply for the 601.

Comment: So I just applied for the 601 since I'm only there for two weeks ... I feel like they are making it confusing on purpose so that you accidentally pay $120

Comment: Normally I'd agree about confusing government websites but the Visa Finder specifications for the 600 on the official site even says directly *If you hold a certain passport, you might be able to apply for a free or cheaper visa.* and points you to 601 and 651 as alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

Both 600 and 601 visas are solely for travellers wishing to enter Australia as a visitor for leisure or business purposes. The difference between a 600 and a 601 visa is that the 601 allows for a maximum stay of 3 months. Moreover, the 601 visa demands less, if not zero, paperwork. This is because the 601 is available only for [a specific set of passport holders, without prior criminal convictions nor debts towards the Australian Government, can apply for a 601 visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/601-#tab-content-1). Presumably, the 601 visa is the result of a bilateral agreement between Australia and all the listed countries. [All travellers not meeting these criteria must apply for a 600 visa.](https://www.border.gov.au/visas/Pages/600-Visitor.aspx?TermStoreId=1cafda66-8aac-4a45-95fa-3e03872913b6&TermSetId=b8c60187-5f41-48c0-98a2-10cb7f1b0ea2&TermId=9fd6b749-b83c-4501-be3d-8edc77cef82d&AdditionalQuestion1=a%20holiday&=true#tab-content-1)

To answer your specific query, you should apply for whichever visa you are eligible for. If you have the choice, pick the cheaper and simpler option. Note that this could even be [the eVisitor (subclass 651) visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-), depending on eligibility.